# Is there a method to swap the left and right hand sides of a set of expressions in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, macros

I have a decent sized set of data that needs to be stored in an active record. In order to prepopulate the form fields on the page, I have already written the following code:

```
Device device = new Device(DeviceID); // device is simply the active record

txtDeviceName.Text = device.Name;
txtNotes.Text = device.Notes;
txtHostName.Text = device.Hostname;
txtAssetTag.Text = device.AssetTag;
txtSerialNumber.Text = device.SerialNumber;
// snip... the list goes on!
```

Is there some sort of the method (built-in functionality, macro, etc.) that I could use to swap each side of the expression such that the data is saved into the active record as opposed to read from it in order to perform a database insert? For example, after highlighting the above code and running the macro, it would become:

```
device.DeviceName = txtDeviceName.Text;
device.Notes = txtNotes.Text;
device.Hostname = txtHostName.Text;
device.AssetTag = txtAssetTag.Text;
device.SerialNumber = txtSerialNumber.Text;
// snip again...
```

Since the number of columns in the database that this active record encapsulates is rather large, it seems like most of this typing could be avoided with a simple automated process.

Obviously this wouldn't work 100% because sometimes there would have to be type conversions (e.g. `int` to `string`) but for the most part I think this would save a lot of time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a macro that will do it:

```
Imports System
Imports EnvDTE
Imports EnvDTE80
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Module Helpers
    Sub SwapAssignment()
        If (Not IsNothing(DTE.ActiveDocument)) Then
            Dim selection As TextSelection = CType(DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection, TextSelection)
            selection.Text = Regex.Replace(selection.Text, "([^\s]*)\s*=\s*([^\s]*);", "$2 = $1;")
        End If
    End Sub
End Module
```

Basically it takes the selected text (either one line or as many lines as you select) and uses a regular expression to swap the values.  Not pretty but then macros never are.

Comment: Neat! Is there a way to perform it on the entire block of text as opposed to just one line?

Comment: Odd, it only works for the 1st line when I select several at once. Are you using VS2008?

Comment: Please note the last fix that only requires a single cast.

Answer (score 0):

Unable to get it to work with the Regex ( must be a visualstudio 2010 thing )
Ive done it the old fashion way using classic splitting. It also includes a check to skip VB and c# comment lines.
Posting it for whoever might need it..

```
Imports System
Imports EnvDTE
Imports EnvDTE80
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Module Helpers
    Sub SwapAssignment()
        If (Not IsNothing(DTE.ActiveDocument)) Then
            Dim selection As TextSelection = CType(DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection, TextSelection)
            Dim lineArray() = selection.Text.Split(vbCrLf)
            Dim output = ""
            For Each line As String In lineArray
                line = line.Trim()

                If line.Length >= 1 Then
                    If line.Substring(0, 1).Equals("'") OrElse line.Substring(0, 1).Equals("/") Then
                        output &= line & vbCrLf
                        Continue For
                    End If
                End If

                If line.Contains(" = ") Then
                    Dim splittedline = line.Split("=")
                    output &= splittedline(1) + " = " + splittedline(0) & vbCrLf
                Else
                    output &= line & vbCrLf
                End If
            Next
            Dim check = output
            selection.Text = output
        End If
    End Sub
End Module
```