# Invert assignment direction in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, regex

I have a bunch of assignment operations in Visual Studio, and I want to reverse them:
i.e

```
i = j;
```

would become

```
j = i;
```

i.e. replacing everything before the equals with what's after the equals, and vice versa

Is there any easy way to do this, say something in the regular expression engine?

Comment: This helped my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/430145/how-can-i-reverse-code-around-an-equal-sign-in-visual-studio

Comment: Can you change the accepted answer? Nowaday CTRL + H does it

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Select the lines you want to swap, Ctrl+H, then replace:

```
{:i}:b*=:b*{:i};
```

with:

```
\2 = \1;
```

with "Look in:" set to "Selection"

That only handles C/C++ style identifiers, though (via the ":i"). Replace that with:

```
{.*}:b*=:b*{.*};
```

to replace anything on either side of the "=".

Also, since you mentioned in a comment you use ReSharper, you can just highlight the "=", Alt+Enter, and "Reverse assignment".

Comment: Resharper's function works perfectly. Can be used on many lines of code at once.

Comment: Since VS2012 this does not work. See this post for VS2012 and later http://stackoverflow.com/questions/430145/how-can-i-reverse-code-around-an-equal-sign-in-visual-studio

Comment: For VS2012+ see this: [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44777693/375958)

Answer (score 17):

Just a slight improvement on Chris's answer...

Ctrl+H, then replace:

```
{:b*}{[^:b]*}:b*=:b*{[^:b]*}:b*;
```

with:

```
\1\3 = \2;
```

(better handling of whitespace, esp. at beginning of line)

**EDIT:**
 For Visual Studio 2012 and higher (I tried it on 2015):
Replace

```
(\s*)([^\s]+)\s*=\s*([^\s]+)\s*;
```

with:

```
$1$3 = $2;
```

Comment: This works great in VS2015... Thanks

Comment: Works fine in VS2010

Answer (score 6):

In Visual Studio 2015+ after selecting code block press `Ctrl + H` (Find & Replace window) and check "Use Regular Expression" option, then:

Find: `(\w+.\w+) = (\w+);`

Replace: `$2 = $1;`

For example:

```
entity.CreateDate = CreateDate;
```

changes to:

```
CreateDate = entity.CreateDate;
```

Thank you @Nagesh and Revious, mentioned details added.

Comment: CTRl + H = Find and replace..

Comment: Worked for me! Note that "Use Regular Expression" option to be checked in Find & Replace dialog box.

Comment: I think this is a bit better `([\w\.]+) = ([\w\.]+);` as it handles changing back the other way too.

Answer (score 2):

The robust way to do this is to use a *refactoring tool*. They know the syntax of the language, so they understand the concept of "assignment statement" and can correctly select the entire expression on either side of the assignment operator rather than be limited to a single identifier, which is what I think all the regular expressions so far have covered. Refactoring tools treat your code as structured code instead of just text. I found mention two Visual Studio add-ins that can do it:

- [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)
- [MZ-Tools](http://www.mztools.com/)

(Inverting assignment isn't technically refactoring since it changes the behavior of the program, but most refactoring tools extend the meaning to include other generic code modifications like that.)

Comment: I actually use ReSharper quite a lot, for various other things, but I wouldn't know how to get it to invert the assigment operator, guess I'm just not that competant with it yet!

Comment: ReSharper calls them "context actions." Place the cursor at the assignment, click the yellow light bulb, and find the reverse-assignment item. http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/documentation/help20/AdvEditing/contextActions.html

Comment: RE: ReSharper, in the current version of ReSharper this is a direct action in the 'hammer' tool that appears when you select an assignment. You can also select multiple assignments.

Answer (score 1):

Please see this question: [Is there a method to swap the left and right hand sides of a set of expressions in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643687?sort=votes)

My answer to that question has a macro that you can use to swap the assignments for a block of code.

Answer (score 1):

I've improved the expression a little.

Replace

```
(\t+)(\s*)(\S*) = (\S*);
```

with

```
$1$2$4 = $3;
```

The reason is, it will look for lines starting with tab (\t). It will skip the lines starting with definition. E.g.:

```
        TestClass tc = new TestClass();
        int a = 75;
        int b = 76;
        int c = 77;

        a = tc.a;
        b = tc.b;
        a = tc.c;
```

Would ignore the int a, int b and int c and swap only the assignments.

Answer (score 0):

what about replace all (CTRL-H)

you can replace for example "i = j;" by "j = i;"

you can use regular expressions in that dialog. I'm not so sure about how you should pop-up help about them however. In that dialog, press F1, then search that page for more information on regular expressions.

I like this dialog because it allows you to go through each replacement. Because the chance of breaking something is high, I think this is a more secure solution

Comment: Ok, how exactly would I do the replace? AFAIK it only allows you to do regex or standard replace, not set one side of something to the other side and vice versa!

Answer (score 0):

You can do search and replace with regular expressions in Visual Studio, but it would be safer to just do a normal search and replace for each assignment you want to change rather than a bulk change.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly I don't have Visual Studio, so I can't try in the target environment, but if it uses standard regexps, you could probably do it like this:
Search for "`(:Al) = (:Al);`", and replace with "`\2 = \1`". (\1 and \2 are references to the first and second capture groups, in this case the parenthesises around the \w:s)

**EDIT**
Ok, not \w... But according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs(VS.80).aspx), we can instead use :Al. Edited above to use that instead.
Also, from the MSDN page I gather that it should work, as the references seem to work as usual.

Comment: unfortunately, Visual Studio doesn't support \w!